# Why are the poor duck and the goose targetted in a derogatory sense In English?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idioms, figurative-language

> **He is a lame duck**
>
> **Becoming  a doctor is a wild goose chase**.
>
> **you bloody goose**
>
> **He was out for a duck or golden duck**.

These are some of  the  terms associated with  duck  and 
geese  which are used in a derogatory sense..

Why  aret  the poor duck and the goose targetted in English  for derogatory  use?

Comment: A goose is not a duck, at least not in England.

Comment: @I I think they belong to the same group

Comment: America either.

Comment: So did you mean 'waterfowl' in general? Nobody says bad things about swans.

Comment: No.I showed the example above. Duck and goose  belong to the same family.

Comment: Unless they are are naturalists or bird freaks, people where I live tend to think of ducks and geese separately.

Comment: Note: a 'duck; in cricket scoring (zero) is so-called because the figure zero ('0') looks like a duck's egg; it was originally called that but got shortened.

Comment: JVL - try saying 'Anatidae' at the average pub gathering and see how far it gets you.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's interesting, since *[goose egg](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goose%20egg)* is leftpondian slang for a nil score, but I've not heard either *duck* or *duck egg* for that.

Comment: In  a wild goose chase, nothing derogatory is being said about the wild goose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to vote this question down as opinion-based, but I decided not to, because I like it. I agree that it is a pity that that amiable creature, the duck, is used in so many derogatory expressions. I'll give you another one: in Britain, having short legs can be called having 'duck's disease'. I think animals tend to appear in expressions mainly because they are familiar, and there are very many well-known animals that are used in e.g. similes - the cunning fox, faithful dog, cautious cat, busy bee, and [so on.](https://www.dogcatplace.com/wildanimals/all-animal-similes)

[image]

Comment: [Duck or grouse](https://www.deviantart.com/cricketumpire/art/Duck-or-grouse-522354523)?

Comment: I am a fairly old BritSpeaker and I had _never heard_ of that.

Comment: You [surprise](https://signothetime.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/great-dixter-72.jpg) me!

Comment: It must be "a thing", as people say these days.